# Read JSON data with crawling "Invalid access"

Tags: python, html, json, ajax, web

I'm crawling data, 
It's [base_url](https://store.naver.com/flights/v2/results?trip=RT&scity1=ICN&ecity1=HKG&scity2=HKG&ecity2=ICN&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&sdate1=2019.03.06.&sdate2=2019.03.13.&fareType=Y)

> chrome - developertool - Network  :
>   international?Adt=1&Chd=0&ECITY1=HKG&ECITY2=ICN&Fa…019.03.13.&TRIP=RT&Where=pc&r=1550032787076&seq=6

Here's all the data I need.

> [json_url](https://store.naver.com/flights/api/realtime/v2/international?Adt=1&Chd=0&ECITY1=HKG&ECITY2=ICN&FareType=Y&Inf=0&MoreKey=246_14c26994-5f86-49c1-bbb4-3e691b4e6145&SCITY1=ICN&SCITY2=HKG&SDATE1=2019.03.06.&SDATE2=2019.03.13.&TRIP=RT&Where=pc&r=1550032787076&seq=6)

I get an error:

> Invalid access

It is judged that there is no right to access.

Asking for a piece of advice on solutions or other solutions using cookies or sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the headers and it should then pull that:

```
import requests

request_url = 'https://store.naver.com/flights/api/realtime/v2/international'

headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Authorization': 'Basic bXlib3R0bGU6d2F0ZXJicm93bg==',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'store.naver.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

params = {
'Adt': '1',
'Chd': '0',
'ECITY1': 'HKG',
'ECITY2': 'ICN',
'FareType': 'Y',
'Inf': '0',
'SCITY1': 'ICN',
'SCITY2': 'HKG',
'SDATE1': '2019.03.06.',
'SDATE2': '2019.03.13.',
'TRIP': 'RT',
'Where': 'pc',
'r': '1550055782230',
'seq': '0'}



jsonObj = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
```

Comment: Your answer will help me a lot.

I need data from the 'fareTypes' in 'jsonObj'. Can I get it?
I will try to apply the answer.